# C - How to add structure members?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, struct

I want to modify this code, such that the structure contains more then one name and one fn (this is a function).

Comment: Add `,` and the internal brackets... And no, you're not adding structure members but array elements.

Comment: Do you mean you want `struct builtin` to have two `name` fields and two `fn` fields, or do you want to add another entry to the array `builtins` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to have more than 1 name, and more than 1 function

Comment: I tried putting , but what about internal brackets ?

Comment: Okay, well before I post an answer, one more question: do you have access to the definition of `struct builtin` and can you modify it?  If the answer is no to either, you're going to have a much harder job.

Comment: Yes I do have access to it

Comment: Instead of modifying to add more names, why don't you just place more entries with different names, but the same function pointer? Something like: `{ { "a", &f }, { "b", &g }, { "c", &f" }, { "d", &g } };`

Comment: Please do not remove everything relevant from your question after you received help. That's not how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So presumably you have something like this already:

```
struct builtin
{
  const char *name;
  int (*fn)( char ** );
};
```

You can just add more fields, either the hard way:

```
struct builtin
{
  const char *name;
  int (*fn)( struct builtin * );
  const char *another_name;
  int (*another_fn)( char ** );
};
```

or the slightly easier way:

```
struct builtin
{
  const char *name[2];
  int (*fn[2])( char ** );
};
```

But after all that, and even after my questions under your post, I struggle to believe this is really what you want to achieve.

EDIT: it *wasn't* really what was wanted...

Try this:

```
struct builtin builtins[NBR_BLTN] =
{
    {
        .name = "echo",
        .fn = exec_echo
    },
    {
        .name = "fish",
        .fn = exec_fish
    },
    // etc.

};
```

Comment: In my header: struct builtin {char *name; int (*fn) (char **builtin)}

Comment: What I want to achieve: compare all the names in the .name, and if found, execute the corresponding .fn

Comment: Okay, then look at @Aconcagua's comment instead.

Comment: Yes thank you, but I do not understand the formatting, I get error syntaxes

Comment: Ok I figured out NBR_BLTN I need to increment it. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: By writing `builtins[NBR_BLTN]` you're promising to provide no more than `NBR_BLTN` initialisers.  In my example I have 2.  In @Aconcagua's comment there are 4.  You should check what value `NBR_BLTN` is.  Alternatively, by writing `builtins[]` it will make the array the right size for all (and only all) those you specify.